# iOS13 App settings properties no more editable

Tags: ios, xcode11, ios13

I am testing an app in iOS 13 using Xcode11. I have some settings properties defined in the .plist file that should be editable from the user. Since iOS 13 I see that they are not editable by default no more.

How could I make them editable?

Comment: which properties are you trying to make editable by user?

Comment: They are custom properties. I used them to insert some information such as URL connection of the app

Comment: do you mean Info.plist?

Comment: No it is the Root.plist file in the Setting.bundle file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With iOS 14 this issue has been solved